# How to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2 with a condition in Excel

Tags: excel

In excel workbook I am trying to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2 with a condition, IF((Sheet1!B2:B80=Sheet2!A2:A80),Sheet2!D2) i am not getting the result.please help me solve this.

I am trying to copy from sheet1 to sheet2 with a condition if the the value in sheet 1,column B  is equal to the value in sheet2 column A the value in column D of sheet 2 should be copied to column G of sheet1

Comment: You should add more details (code snippets, error messages, etc.). The question, stated as it is, is not answerable.

Comment: and a title means a short description to a subject ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try do **debug it step by step**. What happens, if you change your formula in:

```
=IF((Sheet1!B2:B3=Sheet2!A2:A3),Sheet2!D2)
```

?

Or

```
=IF((Sheet1!B2:B3=Sheet2!A2:A3),"the same values")
```

Maybe not all the values are really exactly the same in columns A and B. Or D2 doesn't contain what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following formula in the first cell of column G

```
=IF((Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!A1), Sheet2!D1)
```

then copy this cell down as far as you need to. Excel will change all the cell references for you.

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you are after.

> =IF(Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!D1)

Answer (score 0):

=IF(EXACT(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!A1),Sheet2!D1)